# Help needed - fql query in facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get my friends picture and their last status message with time.

> **message,time FROM status**
>
> **pic_square FROM user**

```
    $status = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT message,time FROM 
status WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=".$user.")");

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($status);
    echo "</pre>";
```

above query returns all statuses, i just want only last status message. Also, how can i modify this query to get pic_square from user table.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

FQL accepts MySQL-style "ORDER BY" and "LIMIT" clauses. Order by time, and limit to one result.

Answer (score 0):

`status.get` is much better for this purpose

Comment: status.get returns only one user's statuses, i need all of my friends last updated status at one shot

Answer (score 0):

As [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2297/ceejayoz) says, your query would need to be:

```
$status = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT message,time FROM 
status WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=".$user.") ORDER BY time LIMIT 1");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($status);
echo "</pre>";
```