# Facebook FQL on Status table not returning accurate results when queried on multiple users

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I went through the below link and wondering whether it is still working?
[Help needed - fql query in facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933857/help-needed-fql-query-in-facebook-api)

I am trying to get the status messages of the currently logged in user and the user's friends.
I used the below query.
fql?q=SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid in(SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))

The above query only returns me the last updated status, but what I am looking for is all the statuses.

When I query on only one user it returns me all the statuses.
For Ex
fql?q=SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid in(XXX)

I did also go through this [Facebook FQL to get all status messages from an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323879/facebook-fql-to-get-all-status-messages-from-an-app) post and added the limit, but still it doesnot work.

Am I missing anything or is that a bug?
Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is just one of those permission problems.

Found the following [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/):

> Reading a user's **status messages** requires the **read_stream**
>   permission.

Comment: I have all the permissions. If I haven't had permission, I would not be able to run the query for single user. It works good for single user, but fails for multiple users.